# Why UITextView won't appear?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a custom tableView Cell, I can't figure out why my UITextView won't show up.
This is my UITextView:

```
    fileprivate let notificationBody: UITextView = {
    let text = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    text.backgroundColor = UIColor.appWhite
    text.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
    text.isScrollEnabled = true
    text.isEditable = false
    text.text = "hjfhsdjfdsfhjksdfhksdjhkfsdjhfshjdfahsdjfdsjklfjsdkfjksdlfjkdsfjklsdlkjfsdjklfsdjklfsdjklfjkldsfjklsdfkjldskjfsdlkjfsdklfjlkdsjflksdajflkdsjflksdjflksdajflksdajflsdkjflsdkjflsdkjflsdkjflsdjflsdjflsdjfsdlkjfslkd"
    text.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.natural
    return text
}()
```

this is how I set it:

```
    fileprivate func setupNotificationBody(){
    addSubview(notificationBody)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        notificationBody.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: notificationTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
        notificationBody.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
        notificationBody.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
        notificationBody.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.dismissNotificationButton.topAnchor, constant: -5)
    ])
}
```

And ofcourse I called setupNotificationBody in Init.
I also have in this cell another button and a uilabel which show up correctly.

Comment: Try giving it a height constraint.

Comment: Has the parent view (`self`) already been added to a super? Is the super and parent (`self`) visible before calling your `setupNotificationBody()`?

Comment: @Kubee doesn't giving it topanchor and bottomanchor is the same as giving it height?

Comment: @ZGski yes, it is.

Comment: Did you use the View Debugger? What did it report?

Comment: Are you giving your cell a fixed height in your UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: @André Thanks, giving the cell an height did solve this, however, I don't want the cell to have a fixed height, I need it to be dynamic sized.

Comment: I see. Just to make sure, you want your cell's height to grow up according to your `UITextView` height, even if it has a lot of lines?

Comment: Oh I assumed you don’t have fixed height cells. Hence the height anchor. Usually the parent takes the height of your child view, not the other way around. Hence a top anchor and a bottom anchor is not enough. You need the height anchor as well.

Comment: By the way. There are many many solutions here. They all depend on your UI however. So you will get varied answers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need your cell to have dynamic height. In this case, you should set the property `isScrollEnabled` in your `UITextView` to false, so the `UITextView` will be able to calculate it's own height.
Also, remember to set the cell height to `UITableView.automaticDimension` in your `UITableViewDelegate`.